# How to check if ASLR is enabled for a process?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-security

Say, if I have a process ID `PID`, is there a WinAPI to find out if [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) is enabled/disabled for that specific process?

Comment: aslr is not per process but per every pe file.

Comment: @RbMm: Oh, so it's per module then. OK, so how do I find that out? Or, do I need to manually examine the PE header. I was hoping to avoid it.

Comment: if you interesting only in *exe* file - you can call `SECTION_IMAGE_INFORMATION sii;ZwQueryInformationProcess(hProcess, ProcessImageInformation, &sii, sizeof(sii), 0);` and check for `sii.ImageDynamicallyRelocated;` this will be work how minimum from win7. may be vista(not check here) - http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/ntmmapi_8h_source.html#l00186

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ASLR enabled not per process but for only those executable which have `IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_DYNAMIC_BASE` in [`IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680339(v=vs.85).aspx)*`.DllCharacteristics`* member. and of course must have relocs.

for check, are exe file (from which process created) dynamically relocated - we can use `NtQueryInformationProcess` with `ProcessImageInformation` - it return [`SECTION_IMAGE_INFORMATION`](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/ntmmapi_8h_source.html#l00186) for exe file. process can be opened with `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` (this is enough. and this let us open even protected processes). the `ImageDynamicallyRelocated` bit is say - are ASLR applied for image.

```
ULONG CheckASLR(ULONG dwProcessId, BOOLEAN& bASLR)
{
    if (HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, FALSE, dwProcessId))
    {
        SECTION_IMAGE_INFORMATION sii;

        NTSTATUS status = NtQueryInformationProcess(hProcess, ProcessImageInformation, &sii, sizeof(sii), 0);

        CloseHandle(hProcess);

        if (0 <= status)
        {
            bASLR = sii.ImageDynamicallyRelocated;

            return NOERROR;
        }

        return RtlNtStatusToDosError(status);
    }

    return GetLastError();
}
```

if we want query this not only for exe file but for specific module, need first get path of this module (can use `GetMappedFileName` ), open file, create section for it and query this section for `SectionImageInformation`. on exit we again got [`SECTION_IMAGE_INFORMATION`](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/ntmmapi_8h_source.html#l00186)

```
NTSTATUS CheckASLR(HANDLE hProcess, PVOID hmod, BOOLEAN& bASLR)
{
    static volatile UCHAR guz = 0;

    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);

    SIZE_T cb = 0, rcb = MAX_PATH*sizeof(WCHAR);

    union {
        PVOID buf;
        PUNICODE_STRING ObjectName;
    };

    NTSTATUS status;
    do 
    {
        if (cb < rcb)
        {
            cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
        }

        if (0 <= (status = NtQueryVirtualMemory(hProcess, hmod, MemoryMappedFilenameInformation, buf, cb, &rcb)))
        {
            HANDLE hFile, hSection;
            IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;

            OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa = { sizeof(oa), 0, ObjectName };

            status = NtOpenFile(&hFile, FILE_GENERIC_READ, &oa, &iosb, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT);

            if (0 <= status)
            {
                status = NtCreateSection(&hSection, SECTION_QUERY, 0, 0, PAGE_READONLY, SEC_IMAGE, hFile);

                NtClose(hFile);

                if (0 <= status)
                {
                    SECTION_IMAGE_INFORMATION sii;

                    status = ZwQuerySection(hSection, SectionImageInformation, &sii, sizeof(sii), 0);

                    NtClose(hSection);

                    if (0 <= status)
                    {
                        bASLR = sii.ImageDynamicallyRelocated;
                    }
                }
            }

            break;
        }

    } while (status == STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW );

    return status;
}
```

Comment: Hey, appreciate the code sample! Let me run a couple of checks and I'll get back to you.

Comment: As a side note, I'm curious, you said that it will even work with a "protected process" -- I keep running into that terminology when I scan processes with [ProcExp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer). What is a `protected process` and how can I tell it apart from a non-protected process? (I mean with a WinAPI.)

Comment: @c00000fd i mean system protected processes. [`IsProtectedProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt809132(v=vs.85).aspx). however only `CheckASLR(ULONG dwProcessId, BOOLEAN& bASLR)` of course will be work for protected processes. for `NTSTATUS CheckASLR(HANDLE hProcess, PVOID hmod, BOOLEAN& bASLR)` we need `PROCESS_VM_OPERATION` access - so you not open so simply protected process

Comment: @c00000fd - [The Evolution of Protected Processes](http://www.alex-ionescu.com/?p=97)

Comment: Oh, OK. I see. You meant the first method. Otherwise I wasn't sure how it would work for reading its VM. But, hey, still pretty good code. Thanks for the info on protected processes.

Comment: @c00000fd - some utilites show protected processes - https://prnt.sc/h5zl5c. the first code snippet (for exe check only) will be worked for system protected processes too, but you need have debug priviledge enabled

Comment: Thanks for your help again. Before I mark it, can you answer these: 1) Why are you checking return value from `NtQueryInformationProcess` to be `>=` 0 instead of `==` 0, like Microsoft do in their sample code? and 2) What software did you make [this screenshot](https://prnt.sc/h5zl5c) with?

Comment: @c00000fd - `>= 0` for `NTSTATUS` this is ok (no error) status. `NT_SUCCESS(Status)` if want. about software - this is one of my personal utilities.

Comment: and I don't know what example you mean. if [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt809132%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) - here used `if (NT_SUCCESS(status))` - so `0 <= status`. some function documented return another `>0` status like `STATUS_TIMEOUT`, `STATUS_USER_APC`, etc. but not this api

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Comment: @RbMm Is it possible to check the same way for CFG ? (on latest win 10)